# Why does object.defineproperty not add the property to the object?

Tags: javascript

I am using `es6` syntax. Why is property `d` added to object `b`, but when I am using Object.defineproperty, the property `c` is not added to the object `b` ?

Here is my code

```js
var a = {
  a: 1
}
var b = {
  a: 5,
  b: 6
}

b['d'] = 33
Object.defineProperty(b, 'c', {
  value: 'eee'
})

var t = {}
Object.assign(t, a, b)
console.log(t)
```

https://es6console.com/iz8m4ux1/

Comment: There is no ES6 specific syntax in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) only copies ***enumerable*** own properties.

[Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) defines non enumerable properties unless the descriptor overrides the default value (`false`) for `enumerable`.

```js
var a ={a:1}
var b={a:5,b:6}
b['d']=33
Object.defineProperty(b,'c',{
 value:'eee',
 enumerable: true
})
var t ={}
Object.assign(t,a,b)
console.log(t)
```

Comment: what is enumerable  ? what is use of this property

Comment: @user944513 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties